# Which is better practice, one client instance for the class or one in each method?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, oop

Let's say that I have a class called `DataService` in my client app. This class have many methods which make calls to a WCF service.

I wonder which is a better practice:

1. To create an instance of WebServiceClient in the class, which is initialized when an instance of the class is created, and is used by the methods, e.g:

   ```
   public class DataService
   {
       MyWebServiceClient client = new MyWebServiceClient();

       public void Method1()
       {
           var v = client.Operation1();

           ...
       }

       public void Method2()
       {
           var v = client.Operation2();

           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Or, to create and initialize an instance of WebServiceClient in each method of the class, e.g:

   ```
   public class DataService
   {      
       public void Method1()
       {
           var client = new MyWebServiceClient();
           var v = client.Operation1();

           ...
       }

       public void Method2()
       {
           var client = new MyWebServiceClient();
           var v = client.Operation2();

           ...
       }
   }
   ```
3. There is also a third option, which is to declare in class and initialize in each method:

   ```
   public class DataService
   {
       MyWebServiceClient client;

       public void Method1()
       {
           client = new MyWebServiceClient();
           var v = client.Operation1();

           ...
       }

       public void Method2()
       {
           client = new MyWebServiceClient();
           var v = client.Operation2();

           ...
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Enough with the solution already; What is the business problem you are addressing? The choice of solution depends on the problem it is solving.

Comment: Part of me wants to downvote this just because of the _third option_...

Comment: @Austin, I have seen so many .net based app built with 3rd option that I thought that it is best practice, lol.

Comment: I just use constructor DI (Autofac works well) and don't worry about the rest. Using a container like Autofac allows me to control the high-level lifetimes simply and handle dependency graphs *without* a lot of work. Now, if `client` *depends on* something in the method call itself, I might use an Autofac "Function" (effectively an implicit factory) approach ..

Comment: Remember that depending on whether the service object is created per call or per session, the methods 1 and 2 may have different semantics.

Comment: If they don't because the service is stateless: flip a coin to pick whichever. Seeing as they do the same and this is bikeshed argument material.

Comment: If you go with options 2 or 3, you will have more places to remember to Close() your proxy if that matters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you have a dependency on another class like this, its usually a good idea to separate out its construction and pass it in (or possibly use dependency injection). This makes your DataService class easier to test, you can more easily mock your WebServiceClient this way.

consider something like...

```
public class DataService
{

    public DataService(MyWebServiceClient client)
    {
        .... //Assign it to a private var...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Constructor injection and one instance per class as in:

```
public class DataService
    {
        IMyWebServiceClient _client;

         public  DataService(IMyWebServiceClient client)
          {
           _client=client
           }

          public  DataService():this(new MyWebServiceClient())
           {

           }


        public void Method1()
        {

            var v = _client.Operation1();

            ...
        }

        public void Method2()
        {

            var v = _client.Operation2();

            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: _Constructor_ injection?

Comment: Constructor injection means you will have a constructor with parameter of external dependancy and you will use this constructor to inject mocks during unit testing and also will be used by Iocs

Comment: **Contractor** injection is where you inject contractors that come on-site with happy drugs so they lower their rates :)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead you could have edited it instead of joking but funny though

Answer (score 0):

I have used method 3 most often in older applications. But recently have seen some code where you have object declaration but instantiation is done by some framework like Spring. The instance is kept inside container. Still learning about that process though.

```
public class DataService
{
    MyWebServiceClient client;

    public void Method1()
    {
        var v = client.Operation1();

        ...
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        var v = client.Operation2();

        ...
    }
}
```